# Clisp REPL error output: how to find line number in file where error occurred?

Tags: lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp, land-of-lisp

I'm working through Land of Lisp, using CLisp, writing the code in Vim with Slimv, then alt-tabbing to another terminal window and loading the file into the REPL with (load 'file.lisp), then running the programs at the REPL.

When I get an error in the REPL, is there any way to ascertain what line in file.lisp the error occurred on?  I don't see line numbers mentioned explicitly in the REPL error output, is there any other way?

I found this similar question, but the only answer says to use something other than Clisp like sbcl, allegro, etc.:

[How can I improve clisp error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060979/how-can-i-improve-clisp-error-messages)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:  Just compile the code instead of loading it into the REPL: `clisp -c file.lisp`.  Compiler error/warnings show the line numbers.  Debug it that way, then load into the REPL.  Good enough for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know what function it occurred in, you can use ":bt" at the REPL prompt when an error happens. It'll print out a GDB-like stacktrace that you can use to figure out which function the error happened at.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` function in clisp has an `:echo` option, see the [implementation notes](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes.html#loadfile). When you use this option your files gets echoed to the output. Hence when an error occurs you can see the corresponding code. For your case the expression would be:

```
(load 'file.lisp :echo t)
```

Some extra options may be useful, such as `:verbose` and `:print`, in which case the expression would be:

```
(load 'file.lisp :verbose t :print t :echo t)
```